# What is the best way to model a spatialtemporal (3d) problem?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, spatial, spatio-temporal

A very common problem in machine learning is that we have time variables. For this we use more statistical approaches like ARIMA or more ML approaches like LSTM.

A sophistication of a time series is a space-time series, that is, we have time in one vector and latitude and longitude in two other vectors,
and since our observations are autocorrelated in these vectors, we have a problem in 3 dimensions.

Traditional machine learning models do not understand this behavior, for them the observations are independent of each other which is not true in this case.

An example: I have a history of moving people around cities (either individually or in aggregates or small polygons) over the days and I want to predict what this flow will be like.

What would be the right way to deal with such problems?
Do we have a super 3d LSTM?

Comment: How do you want to represent time (a stochastic or a deterministic trend) and how do you want to represent space? There are many more options than ARIMA or LSTM for the time-only case and many options for spatial modelling. Making the two interact may be easier in some frameworks than others. I often approach such data from a penalised spline framework, where a 3-d tensor product smooth of the form `te(x, y, t)` might be sufficient, but this makes certain assumptions about how one thinks space and time affect the response. Without more detail, your Q may is too broad to answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will edit the question to make it less generic.

Comment: You might approach this problem by individually examining a time-driven outlier-robust model for each longitude/latitude combination and evaluate possible commonalities/similarities in the models before extending .

Comment: I think the answer to this question depends on how general your definition of "machine learning" is. There **are** spatiotemporal statistical models, such as https://www.amazon.com/Statistics-Spatio-Temporal-Data-Noel-Cressie/dp/0471692743/ref=sr_1_9?keywords=spatiotemporal+data+analysis&qid=1570843043&sr=8-9 but these aren't, as far as I am aware, models that have LSTM units.